# Spring Redis connection fail socket timeout: read timed out

Tags: spring, sockets, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

In the process of page access will suddenly read the timeout error, it seems to be caused by the lack of access. I did not make special equipment for Redis, all the default parameters.

The following is the Spring Boot configuration file:

```
## Redis
 redis:
  host: 127.0.0.1
  password: eee!1234
  database: 1
  timeout: 5
  pool:
    min-idle: 1
    max-active: 100


 cache:
  type: redis


 session:
  store-type: redis
  timeout: 5
  redis.namespace: application
```

This is the error log:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:67) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:242) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.select(JedisConnection.java:984) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.<init>(JedisConnection.java:227) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:349) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:129) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:92) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:79) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:194) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:169) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:91) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.entries(DefaultHashOperations.java:220) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.entries(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:102) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:432) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:402) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:245) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:327) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:344) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:217) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.loadContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:202) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:239) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.select(BinaryJedis.java:523) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.select(JedisConnection.java:982) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:196) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
```

For additional information on this issue, please visit
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9393

Answer (score 4):

Timeout is in *milliseconds*, you are not allowing enough time to establish the connection.

Comment: I also encountered the same problem, and you said it correctly, because the unit of timeout is milliseconds, not seconds.